# Android App Architecture for checking for new mail

Tags: android, gmail, jakarta-mail, imap, gmail-api

I want to build an android app that notifies a user when he has new mail.

I am planning on using [this JavaMail port](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/) or the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) or a combination of both.

The question I have is how to check for new mail.

I could have a background service that even when the app is not running keeps polling for new mail but I feel like that would be bad because

- Frequent polling would be wasteful, specially when it comes to battery usage
- If polling frequency is not high enough other mail clients would be far superior since they would always notify the user of incoming mail before my app.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem without having to build an entire backend that offloads this task?

Comment: Have you looked into IMAP IDLE?

Comment: I don't think I understand how it works. Wouldn't I have to have the client polling for it every now and then with IDLE as well?

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that my gut feeling tells me that IDLE might be lightweight, but it still involves keeping a connection open in the background if I'm not mistaken and I'm trying to build an efficient mobile app that gets notified for new mail.

Comment: IDLE requires the connection to be open, but you don't have to do anything to poll for new messages; the server will notify you when new messages arrive.  (You will need to use the connection every 30 minutes to keep it connected.)

Comment: Can anybody comment on how I would do that as an android app? Is the plan to keep use the AlarmManager that will fire-off a background service (IntentService) every now and then even after the app is no longer being used? And then would the service fire a notification that would wake up my app?

Comment: The plan is yours to make. You're entirely right that frequent polling will burn the battery. As will keeping the radio on all the time. Quite simply, function comes with a price.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there currently is no mechanism to receive updates automatically when new mail arrives. I would recommend logging an enhancement request for push notification support in the API in the [Apps API issue tracker](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list). In lieu of this, you can minimize resource utilization by only doing a full sync once, and then keeping track of the history id and doing only [partial syncs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync#partial_synchronization) from that point.